# Вывод данных в цикле while (PHP) из массива JSON

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть массив JSON:

```
{"city":{"id":2013159,"name":"London", "list":
[
{"dt":1459360800,"main":{"temp":-6.55,"temp_min":-6.55,"temp_max":-2.34}}
{"dt":1459425600,"main":{"temp":-8.55,"temp_min":-10.55,"temp_max":-4.34}}
{"dt":1459458000,"main":{"temp":-10.56,"temp_min":-15.55,"temp_max":-8.34}}
]}
```

он в переменной **$weatherDatas_json** 
Преобразовал данные формата JSON в переменную массива

```
$weatherDatas = json_decode($weatherDatas_json, true);
```

Чтобы вывести данные **dt** с 1(*нулевого*) элемента массива делаю следующее:

```
$weatherDt = $weatherDatas['city']['list'][0][dt];
echo $weatherDt;
```

как вывести все **dt** из массива? Подскажите пожалуйста конструкцию while. не могу подставить номер элемента массива автоматически, причем данных **dt**(элементов массива) может быть разное количество

Comment: а обязательно while? может так подойдет: `foreach ($array as $key => $value) { echo "Index: $key, value: $value"; }`? Через while можно, например, так: `while ($value = array_pop($array)) { echo $value; }` Способов вообще куча, в зависимости от задачи некоторые могут не подойти, но для вывода должно все сработать

Answer (score 1):

зачем тебе while? Тут однозначно foreach (while - медленнее в порядок просто)
Как ограничивать кол-во выводимых? заводишь счетчик $limit, плюсуешь его когда надо, а в начале цикла проверку:

```
foreach ($weatherDatas["list"] as $key => $value) {
     if ($limit == 5) break;
     echo $value["dt"],"\n";
     $limit++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/ - вот здесь описано очень хорошо

Сделал следующим образом:
в первую очередь, для визуального понимания массива, лучше его вывести через оператор:

```
print_r($weatherDatas);
```

далее для выборки всех элементов из массива используется оператор:

```
foreach ($weatherDatas["list"] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["dt"],"\n";
  }
```

единственное, **как ограничить количество выводимых элементов**, например выводить *5 первых элементов* массива?

Comment: Если нужно ограничение, принято заводить цикл со счетчиком. `for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { $curItem = $weatherDatas['list'][$i]; var_dump($curItem;); }`

Comment: Ну а $key тебе на что?

Comment: @Ипатьев: Где вы нашли `$key`? Роль ключа, как можно заметить, заключена в `$i`